# VB6 and Com debug issues after XP Service Pack 3 install

Tags: com, vb6, debugging, windows-xp-sp3

My company recently upgraded our PCs to XP service pack 3.
We still have some vb6 apps that connect to an EJB server via a JCOM bridge.
These apps still work as compiled exes but i noticed that during debugging the IDE hangs when it tries to create a JCOM object. 
I suspected it was as a result of the XP upgrade and was able to confirm this by successfully debugging the same code on a machine with XP SP2.

I have vb sp6 installed (Vs6sp6B.exe)  I notice there are further versions available called  vs6sp6b1, vs6sp6b2, vs6sp6b3 and vs6sp6b4 from here
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=83bf08e6-012d-4db2-8109-20c8d7d5c1fc#filelist

Does this issue sound familiar to anyone? Would appreciate some advice before attempting to install these upgrades.

Thanks

Comment: It's not a further version, it's a multi-file version for those with slow connections. `"Customers with broadband connections are encouraged to download the one-file version."`

Comment: Thanks GSerg. That saves me trying to install them, still leaves me with the main issue though.

Comment: As I recall this is most likely down to some arcane permissions issues with DCOM : this was the closest I could find to the article in question : http://p2p.wrox.com/archives/asp_ecommerce/2002-09/19.php : I remember getting this to work properly for ASP apps - with both VB6 and Interdev both stopping on breakpoints correctly - a sum total of once. I now keep my VB6 devkit in a VM, so if I ever have to do it again, I'll snapshot it, because it's a fiddle, as I recall.